# Probleme when using file descriptors on bash

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Hy everyone. 
I made a fd of file with

`exec 7<file`

And then when using

> cat <&7

It shows what's in the file .
But when i use it again it shows nothing . 
I didn't undrestand why. 
Someone who can help please.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can only read lines from a stream once. If you need to re-read the file descriptor again, you'll need to `exec 7<file` again.

Comment: In other words, the file descriptor remembers the read position as long as it's open, even across programs. `cat` _could_ in theory seek back to 0, but it doesn't.